# How to (really) force a restart remotely

Tags: windows-xp, freeze, reboot, remote

I'm managing a small remote server and recently I've been having issues related to USB driver (or at least I believe so) disabling some of USB controllers and preventing system restart. It doesn't occur often enough to test properly.

When I try to restart with `shutdown -r -f -t 0` I see programs and some services being shutdown, then I get disconnected from remote session and for all I know computer is stuck in a state where it is still on network, but no longer accessible remotely.

I am wondering if there's any (possibly hacky) method to really force a restart, that cannot be hindered by frozen processes,services or drivers? As a last resort, I am considering a script to shutdown USB drivers and services (if needed), however, I wish i avoid it, because again, it is hard to test if it actually works, because I don't know if restart will freeze until it happens.

Comment: A network connected Arduino with a relay connected to the reset header on the motherboard will do the trick

Comment: The event viewer should show log when it starts up

Answer (score 0):

The only additional way I know is remote killing the lsass.exe process like this:

TASKKILL /S hostname /U username /P password /F /IM LSASS.EXE /T

This very often fails but it's worth trying.

If you have a remote server you really want a KVM over IP or ILO setup though.